# Passing Multiple ids to single parameter in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have table emloyee with following data.

```
Id    Name     Country   

1     John      USA

2     Smith     USA

3     Jack      IND

4     Lory      UK

5     Miller    USA
```

I want to get result by calling stored procedure like this

```
call getEmployeeDetailsByCountry('IND,UK');

Result:
Id    Name     Country   

3     Jack      IND

4     Lory      UK
```

My Procedure is

```
select * from employee
where if( (LOCATE(',','IND,USD')>0),
Country in (concat('\'',REPLACE('IND,USD', ',', '\',\''),'\''))
, Country in ('IND,USD'));
```

Here it replaces 'IND,USD' to 'IND','USD'. 
But result is no rows.... Can anyone help me to find..... thank you

Comment: Why not use MySQL's [`IN()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) comparison operator, e.g. `SELECT * FROM employee WHERE Country IN ('IND', 'UK')`?

Comment: do you have a good reason why you want to use a stored procedure for something simple like this?

Comment: Is it simple ? But how ?? i am passing more than one data to a single parameter say country . Its not SELECT * FROM employee WHERE Country IN ('IND', 'UK').................... Pls check my question...Its SELECT * FROM employee WHERE Country IN ('IND,UK')

Comment: 'IND,UK'.... Its not 'IND' , 'UK'

Comment: 2 different data to single parameter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use FIND_IN_SET instead of IN

```
    SELECT * 
FROM product
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(country, 'IND,USD');
```

Try this i think this will solve your problem

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you use a query with a simple [`IN` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) in the `where` clause?

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE Country IN ('IND', 'UK');
```

Comment: I want to pass multiple parameter like 'IND,UK' to single parameter in procedure. eg: In Procedure  parameter country accepts  'IND,UK'. So how can i use SELECT * FROM employee WHERE Country IN ('IND', 'UK'); ???? its multiple parameters right ????